# How to get a boolean indicating if a search is using regex?

Tags: datatables

I know that the methods `instance.search()` and `instance.column(1).search()` are returning a search string. But, how can I know if they should be triggered like a regex? I mean, regex search can be activated by either using

```
$("something").DataTable({
    "search": {
      "regex": true
    }
});
```

or by activating the regex flag in the `.search()` method. But even then, the above named methods return a string, not a RegExp.

So when calling one of the above methods, how am I able to know if they should be handled like a RegExp?

Comment: `.search()` never returns a "search string" nor a "RegExp" it always return an API instance.

Comment: That's not true, I tried it myself. It returns a string.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()): `Returns string`

Comment: I thought you would actually perform a search, yes search() with no params return the last search string.